# removed stuff and steam won't work anymore

Tags: 14.10, steam

I was running into some issues running steam in ubuntu 14.10 and people on the internet suggested to remove some stuff in order to resolve my issue.. So I ran this little gem over here:

```
rm -rf libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 /var/spool/postfix/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /var/spool/postfix/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

and now each time I run steam i get this other little gem in a popup window:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
```

I tried everything from reinstalling all that relates to libgcc to reinstalling steam and I`m at the breaking point where I`m about to reinstall Ubuntu to make it work..

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue by taking each element that was removed and searched it via Synaptic Package Manager and reinstalled them.